# Is it possible to get incoming call data to application in Android

Tags: android, audio, phone-call

I would like to know if we can get Incoming call data to the application in Android.

I will be using this incoming call data to record the call or for the purpose of call streaming from my application.

I read Audio manager and Telephony manager class provided by Android , but I could get an API which can give the data of incoming call.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible for regular calls (GSM, CDMA, etc.). For VoIP calls technically it is possible, provided that you have access to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Audio Source of Mediarecorder object to Voice Call.

```
final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
```

Comment: This is known for not working. Have you tested it on any phone?

Comment: Even I read in some places that the recording with VOICE_CALL options does not work , I am not sure. Kindly let e know if any one has tested it.